# Scraping entire HTML tags with Nokogiri

Tags: html, css, ruby, html-parsing, nokogiri

I've searched everywhere and all I found was to do CSS selection with Nokogiri, what I am after is simply to get rid off all HTML tags.

For example this:

```
<html>
   <head><title>My webpage</title></head>
   <body>
   <h1>Hello Webpage!</h1>
   <div id="references">
      <p><a href="http://www.google.com">Click here</a> to go to the search engine Google</p>
      <p>Or you can <a href="http://www.bing.com">click here to go</a> to Microsoft Bing.</p>
      <p>Don't want to learn Ruby? Then give <a href="http://learnpythonthehardway.org/">Zed Shaw's Learn Python the Hard Way</a> a try</p>
   </div>

   <div id="funstuff">
      <p>Here are some entertaining links:</p>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="http://youtube.com">YouTube</a></li>
         <li><a data-category="news" href="http://reddit.com">Reddit</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://kathack.com/">Kathack</a></li>
         <li><a data-category="news" href="http://www.nytimes.com">New York Times</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>

   <p>Thank you for reading my webpage!</p>

   </body>
<p>Addition</p>
</html> 
Extra content
```

Should ouptut as:

```
Hello Webpage!

Click here to go to the search engine Google

Or you can click here to go to Microsoft Bing.

Don't want to learn Ruby? Then give Zed Shaw's Learn Python the Hard Way a try

Here are some entertaining links:

YouTube
Reddit
Kathack
New York Times
Thank you for reading my webpage!
Addition
Extra content
```

How can I do that by using Nokogiri? Also what else can I do to scrape other code such as Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = %q{ 
  <html>
   <head><title>My webpage</title></head>
   <body>
   <h1>Hello Webpage!</h1>
   <div id="references">
     <p><a href="http://www.google.com">Click here</a> to go to the search engine Google</p>
     <p>Or you can <a href="http://www.bing.com">click here to go</a> to Microsoft Bing.</p>
     <p>Don't want to learn Ruby? Then give <a href="http://learnpythonthehardway.org/">Zed Shaw's    Learn Python the Hard Way</a> a try</p>
   </div>

   <div id="funstuff">
    <p>Here are some entertaining links:</p>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="http://youtube.com">YouTube</a></li>
     <li><a data-category="news" href="http://reddit.com">Reddit</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://kathack.com/">Kathack</a></li>
     <li><a data-category="news" href="http://www.nytimes.com">New York Times</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>

   <p>Thank you for reading my webpage!</p>

   </body>
</html>
}

doc = Nokogiri::XML(html)
body = doc.search('body')
puts body.text.gsub(/<.*?\/?>/, '')
```

Comment: This just looks for the body though. What I meant was all the content regardless of their html tag. Please see the updated example

Comment: nokogiri parses HTML/XML. If you have a regular string and you want to get rid of all the html tags - just do the following str = str.gsub(/<.*?\/?>/, '') and that will get rid of all the html tags

Comment: What about javascript and other stuff?

Comment: You want to get rid of javascript?

Comment: Yes, I also want to scrape Javascript.

Comment: Can you post an updated example please? What is the original (input) and what do you want the output to be. I am still trying to see if you are after nokogiri parsing or regular expression magic (or a hybrid).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do what you would like, I would look into using Loofah which wraps Nokogiri under the hood.

In Loofah you would do something like:

```
document = Loofah.fragment(html)
document.scrub!(:prune).text
```

Prune scrub removes all the unsafe tags and subtrees,  and text outputs new line character per node.